# MKMapView is not deallocating memory for MKUserLocation

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview, instruments, heapshot

I have a navigation controller in which VC1 pushes VC2 onto the navigation stack. VC2 has a MKMapView in a tab based view, with user location turned on. When I check for repeat allocations with instruments using Heapshot Analysis tool, I repeatedly find some MKUserLocation objects not being deallocated when I come back to VC1.
[image]

I have removed all annotations and also disabled user location upon dealloc. What could be the reason for this heap growth?

VC1 code that pushes VC2 onto the navigation stack:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    vc2.index = indexPath.row;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc2 
                                           animated:YES];
    [vc2 release];
    vc2 = nil;
    return nil;
}
```

The dealloc code in VC2:

```
- (void)dealloc {
//Other UILabel, UITextField objects dealloc methods go here
//The next four lines of code do not make a difference even if they are in viewWillDisappear
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
[self.mapView.layer removeAllAnimations];
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;//This line does not make a difference in heapshot
mapView.delegate = nil;
[mapView release];
mapView = nil;
[super dealloc];
```

}

Also, there is no heap growth, if I do not switch on the user location.

**Update:** I have tested this on the simulator and on an iPad 3G+WiFi, and I find this heap growth in both cases.

Comment: Is dealloc in VC2 actually getting called?

Comment: Yes, all the other objects get deallocated. I checked it by taking out dealloc for another object and it started showing up in the heapshot.

Comment: Can you post the VC2 dealloc method and the code in VC1 that creates VC2 and pushes it?  Have you tried turning the user location off and setting the map's delegate to nil in VC2's viewWillDisappear?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you should call `[super dealloc];` at the end of dealloc.  At the start of dealloc, check if mapView is nil.  Also, are you creating mapView in code or IB?  Is it possible you have more than one map view (one created in IB and one in code)?

Comment: I forgot to mention the [super dealloc] here updated the code to reflect the same. I am creating the mapView in IB, and I don't have any code that creates another mapView.

Comment: Is the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method in VC2 still getting called after you go back to VC1?  In the simulator, try Debug|Location|Freeway Drive to get continuous updates.

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating the `MKMapView` in IB, you should be releasing/`nil`-ing it in [`-viewDidUnload`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) AND `-dealloc`.

If you don't, if your view is unloaded/reloaded during the lifetime of your view controller, all your view elements (that are set up as retained properties, anyway) will be leaked on reload.

There seems to be a decent amount of chatter on the web/SO that says this was an API bug pre-5.0.1. What version of the SDK are you building against?

Also, shot in the dark: try only

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
```

or

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
[self.mapView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
```

instead of the order of these commands you're using now.

Could be that you're removing the annotation for `MKUserLocation` before `MKMapView` has a chance to tear it down correctly?

Comment: I've tried releasing it in viewDidUnload and dealloc but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I tried both approaches, but neither change the multiple allocation problem. I am on the latest SDK 5.0.1, so is the device that I tested it on.